# create session in Perl and read session variables in PHP

Tags: php, perl, session

I have a Perl script that tries to make a post request to a PHP server.
Used LWP::UserAgent for post request and CGI::Session to handle sessions.

Right now, no big issue on post, but after set session variable: username in Perl, I could not get value from `$_SESSION['username']`. Tried using PHP::Session, no luck neither.

Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use CGI::Session;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $cgi = CGI->new();
my $session = CGI::Session->new( 'serializer:php' );
$session->param('username', 'dev');
print "::Perl session id::" . $session->id() . "::\n";

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'http://localhost/test.php';
my $response = $browser->post( $url,
  [ 
    'date' => '2015-02-25'
  ]
);

die "$url error: ", $response->status_line
 unless $response->is_success;

my $file_data = $response->content();
print $file_data;
```

Php:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "::PHP session id::" . session_id() . "::\n";
echo "::" . $_POST['date'] . "::\n";
echo "::" . $_SESSION['username'] . "::\n";    
?>
```

By executing Perl script, I get output:

```
::Perl session id::737ba07ad1a2ced0be07cd303cf08afe::
::PHP session id::ri60ivtb32lglcrqv4ug1sb2i5::
::2015-02-25::
::::
```

`$_SESSION['username']` is not retrieved correctly. And session ids are different.

Comment: set a cookie in perl PHPSESSID with the perl sessioin id in it

Comment: Are those two applications on the same server?

Comment: perl script is located under C:\wamp\ and session file is created under C:\wamp\tmp

Comment: @feng63600 I think you misunderstood how it works. Why need to be session id value from perl script  equal PHP session_id? Each session id in both scripts create separately.

Comment: @KostiaShiian I see. Why session variable set in Perl cannot retrieve in PHP then?

Comment: You have different session IDs, so you end up with different session.

Comment: To amplify @el.pescado, you started a session in Perl and then you started another session in PHP. You don”t want two sessions—just one. That’s why the session IDs are different.

Answer (score -2):

I did not find an ideal module for Perl to handle SFTP/FTP on windows.
Instead, get some luck using Win32::OLE->new('WinSCP.Session').

Usage: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_perl